# Sagemakeer serverless deployment fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-serverless, amazon-ecr

I tried to deploy a model in sagemaker as serverless.

Steps:

1. Created docker container and pushed to ECR [Success]
2. Created model in sagemaker [Success]
3. Created endpoint configuration in sagemaker [Success]
4. Create endpoint in sagmeker [Failed]

No logs are seen in cloudwatch. The endpoint creation just fails with "Received server error (0) from model with message "An error occurred while handling request as the model process exited."."

I have made similar deployments before successfully. But not able to do it now. Please guide what this error means.

Comment: Can you be running out of memory?

Comment: No. I found the issue. When i create from windows, there some issue with the line "#!/usr/bin/env python" which gives the errors: 
/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines

I moved the code to a ubuntu machine and created the docker. With that the issue was solved. Now the model is deployed successfully.

Any idea what's causing the issue and how it can be done from windows itself?

Comment: Your message shows that windows messed up with line endings in the file, replaced normal LF with CRLF. Then bash parses the shebang, where first line is `#!/usr/bin/env python\r\n`. It strips newline and asks `env` to find an executable called `python\r`, which obviously does not exist. I don't have any windows environment available, but you should be able to configure line endings in your editor or IDE.

Comment: Yes. that seems to be correct. Got the same when adding to git too. Thanks.